# Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component react-navigation version-5

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I got this error when i click on a button

```
  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.circle}
      onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.navigate('User')}}>
```

Comment: what kind of error you got please specify

Comment: Whenever i want to move another screen by clicking on a button then i get this error..

Comment: The code you've shown is fine. The problem is somewhere else in your code. So add more relevant code to the question and/or create a [snack](https://snack.expo.io/) and link it.